# Machine Learning- apply on Time Series Analysis with multidimensional features

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I am trying to make predictions on weather forecast (which is a time series analysis problem) with multiple features on each time unit (say temperature, humidity, etc).

So my data become like this:
Day 1- temp(1), humidity(1)
Day 2- temp(2), humidity(2)
Day 3- temp(3), humidity(3)

If I want to arrange each row vector as individual training example, how should I arrange the order of data? Would it be the following?

temp(1), humidity(1), temp(2), humidity(2), temp(3), humidity(3)

It seems not quite right intuitively.  I have been thinking of using recurrent neural network such as Restricted Boltzmann Machines but it seems to be too difficult for me to implement. (I am using Neuroph with Java which is easier for me as I am not very familiar with programming).

Comment: Welcome to CV. The quick answer is that you want to stack your data up into a long, narrow file where each record corresponds to a single day's values with three features -- day, temp and humidity.

Comment: Thanks. But would this sort of ordering ignore the effect of time series(if I use ordinary machine learning algorithm rather than recurrent NN)?    Let's say for another example, if I were to do pattern recognition for stock price(features become price, volume, PE,etc), then the information embedded in data sequence would definitely mean a lot to prediction accuracy.

Comment: Absolutely not! This ordering *captures* the variation attributable to time.

Comment: Is there any example available for reference for this type of ordering?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out? Try your pushed down, flat file approach too and see what you get.